# Excel VBA Macros: Open a file from an incomplete file name and then designate it as a destination to paste

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with multiple tabs on it and each tab needs to be pasted into specific sheets in different workbooks in a folder. What I did so far was create an InputBox to paste in the file path to the folder when the macro starts.

From there I made a wildcard additions to match part of the first file name since the ends of the file name changes. So far it successfully opens the file I am searching for.

I am now stuck on trying to get the actual full file name so I can designate the now opened filed as a destination to paste the data in. Is there a way to grab the file name from the open folder and have a specific sheet in it as the paste destination?

This is what I have so far pretty much:

```
Dim MyPath As String

MyPath = Input box ("Enter Path here")

If Right (MyPath, 1) <> " \ " Then

MyPath = MyPath & " \ "

End If

Dim WBName As String

WBName = Dir(MyPath & "*part of first wb name * " & ".xl*")

If WBName <> "" Then

Workbooks.Open (Mypath & WBName)

End If
```

Comment: Use a `Workbook` variable: `Dim wb As Workbook`, `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Mypath & WBName)`, then refer to `wb`.

Comment: Some 'waste of spaces' in your code... `If Right (MyPath, 1) <> " \ " Then` should be `If Right (MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then`, `MyPath = MyPath & " \ "` instead of `MyPath = MyPath & "\"`, `WBName = Dir(MyPath & "*part of first wb name * " & ".xl*")` should be `WBName = Dir(MyPath & "*" & part of first wb name &   "*.xls*")`, where `part of first wb nam` must be a `String` variable to keep what it suggests. About the workbook setting, the above comment certainly should clarify the issue...